# error while feeding noise and emmbeding to generator

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am implementing a conditional GAN for image generation from text embedding from scratch.
after concatenating the noise and the emmbeddings i am getting the following error:`RuntimeError: Given transposed=1, weight of size [456, 512, 4, 4], expected input[32, 1049088, 1, 1] to have 456 channels, but got 1049088 channels instead`
Generator:

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim=300, latent_dim=100, image_size=64, num_channels=3):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        self.embedding_size = embedding_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.image_size = image_size

        # Define embedding processing layers
        self.embedding_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_dim,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        # Define noise processing layers
        self.noise_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim, image_size * image_size * 4),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(image_size * image_size * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        # Define image processing layers
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latent_dim + 256, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, num_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
    def get_latent_dim(self):
        return self.latent_dim
    def forward(self, embeddings,noise):
        # Process embedding
        embedding_features = self.embedding_layers(embeddings)

        # Process noise
        
        noise_features = self.noise_layers(noise)

        # Combine features
        features = torch.cat((embedding_features, noise_features), dim=1)
        print(features.shape)
        features=features.unsqueeze(2)
        features=features.unsqueeze(3)
        # Generate image
        image = self.conv_layers(features)

        return image
```

Discriminator

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim=300, image_size=64, num_channels=3,):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        # Define image processing layers
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(87040, 1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(1024, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # Define embedding processing layers
        self.embedding_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_dim,512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, images, embeddings):
        # Process embedding
        embedding_features = self.embedding_layers(embeddings)
        embedding_features = embedding_features.view(embedding_features.shape[0], 1, 64, 64)

        # Combine features
        features = torch.cat((images, embedding_features), dim=1)

        # Classify
        classification = self.conv_layers(features)
       
        return classification
```

train function

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from tqdm import tqdm

def train_gan(generator, discriminator, dataset, batch_size, num_epochs, device):
    """
    Trains a conditional GAN with a generator and a discriminator using a PyTorch dataset containing text embeddings and images.
    """
    # Set up loss functions and optimizers
    adversarial_loss = nn.BCELoss()
    generator_optimizer = optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    discriminator_optimizer = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    
    # Set up data loader
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    generator.to(device)
    discriminator.to(device)
    # Train the GAN
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader)):
            # Load data and labels onto the device
            text_embeddings = data['text_embedding'].to(device)
            real_images = data['image'].to(device)
            
            # Generate fake images using the generator and the text embeddings
            noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to(device)
            fake_images = generator(text_embeddings,noise)
            print("generator image shape:")
            print(fake_images.shape)
            # Train the discriminator
            discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            real_labels = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1).to(device)
            fake_labels = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1).to(device)
            real_predictions = discriminator(real_images, text_embeddings)
            real_loss = adversarial_loss(real_predictions, real_labels)
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images.detach(), text_embeddings)
            fake_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_predictions, fake_labels)
            discriminator_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
            discriminator_loss.backward()
            discriminator_optimizer.step()
            
            # Train the generator
            generator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images, text_embeddings)
            generator_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_predictions, real_labels)
            generator_loss.backward()
            generator_optimizer.step()
            
            # Save generated images and model checkpoints every 500 batches
            if i % 500 == 0:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    fake_images = generator(text_embeddings[:16]).detach().cpu()
                save_image(fake_images, f"images\generated_images_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.png", normalize=True, nrow=4)
                torch.save(generator.state_dict(), f"images\generator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), f"images\discriminator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                
        # Print loss at the end of each epoch
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}] Discriminator Loss: {discriminator_loss.item()}, Generator Loss: {generator_loss.item()}")
```

main

```py
# defining hyperparamter 
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
embedding_dim=768
img_size=512
latent_dim=200
batch_size=32
num_epochs=100
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
#define the main components
generator=Generator(embedding_dim=embedding_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim, image_size=img_size)
discriminator=Discriminator(embedding_dim=embedding_dim,image_size=img_size)

train_gan(generator=generator,
          discriminator=discriminator,
          dataset=dataset,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          num_epochs=num_epochs,
          device=device,)
```

as for my dataset, it consists of images and text embeddings with the following shape

```
torch.Size([3, 512, 512])
torch.Size([768])
```

full stack trace

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 train_gan(generator=generator,
      2           discriminator=discriminator,
      3           dataset=dataset,
      4           batch_size=batch_size,
      5           num_epochs=num_epochs,
      6           device=device,)

Cell In[5], line 30, in train_gan(generator, discriminator, dataset, batch_size, num_epochs, device)
     28 # Generate fake images using the generator and the text embeddings
     29 noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to(device)
---> 30 fake_images = generator(text_embeddings,noise)
     31 print("generator image shape:")
     32 print(fake_images.shape)

File ~\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:727, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725     result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726 else:
--> 727     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728 for hook in itertools.chain(
    729         _global_forward_hooks.values(),
    730         self._forward_hooks.values()):
    731     hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

Cell In[4], line 57, in Generator.forward(self, embeddings, noise)
     55 features=features.unsqueeze(3)
     56 # Generate image
---> 57 image = self.conv_layers(features)
     59 return image

File ~\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:727, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725     result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726 else:
--> 727     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728 for hook in itertools.chain(
    729         _global_forward_hooks.values(),
    730         self._forward_hooks.values()):
    731     hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

File ~\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py:117, in Sequential.forward(self, input)
    115 def forward(self, input):
    116     for module in self:
--> 117         input = module(input)
    118     return input

File ~\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:727, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725     result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726 else:
--> 727     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728 for hook in itertools.chain(
    729         _global_forward_hooks.values(),
    730         self._forward_hooks.values()):
    731     hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

File ~\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py:927, in ConvTranspose2d.forward(self, input, output_size)
    922     raise ValueError('Only `zeros` padding mode is supported for ConvTranspose2d')
    924 output_padding = self._output_padding(
    925     input, output_size, self.stride, self.padding, self.kernel_size, self.dilation)
--> 927 return F.conv_transpose2d(
    928     input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride, self.padding,
    929     output_padding, self.groups, self.dilation)

RuntimeError: Given transposed=1, weight of size [456, 512, 4, 4], expected input[32, 1049088, 1, 1] to have 456 channels, but got 1049088 channels instead
```

i think also i am doing another mistakes while implementing the architecture if you could help me to correct them

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but this code worked for me

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim=300, image_size=64, num_channels=3,):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        # Define image processing layers
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(1114112, 1024),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(1024, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # Define embedding processing layers
        self.embedding_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_dim,49152),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(49152),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, images, embeddings):
        # Process embedding
        embedding_features = self.embedding_layers(embeddings)
        embedding_features=embedding_features.reshape(embedding_features.shape[0],3, 32, 512)
        # Combine features
        features = torch.cat((images, embedding_features), dim=2)

        # Classify
        classification = self.conv_layers(features)
        return classification
```

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim=300, latent_dim=100, image_size=64, num_channels=3):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        self.embedding_size = embedding_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.image_size = image_size

        # Define embedding processing layers
        self.embedding_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_dim,8192),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(8192),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        # Define noise processing layers
        self.noise_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim, 8192),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(8192),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        # Define image processing layers
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 16, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, num_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
    def get_latent_dim(self):
        return self.latent_dim
    def forward(self, embeddings,noise):
        # Process embedding
        embedding_features = self.embedding_layers(embeddings)
        # Process noise
        noise_features = self.noise_layers(noise)
        # Combine features
        
        embedding_features=embedding_features.reshape(embedding_features.size(0),8, 8, 128)
        noise_features=noise_features.reshape(noise_features.size(0),8, 8, 128)
        features = torch.cat((embedding_features, noise_features), dim=2)
        # Generate image
        image = self.conv_layers(features)

        return image
```

```
import gc
def clear_memory():
    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm

def train_gan(generator, discriminator, dataset, batch_size, num_epochs, device):
    
    # Set up loss functions and optimizers
    adversarial_loss = nn.BCELoss()
    generator_optimizer = optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    discriminator_optimizer = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    
    # Set up data loader
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    generator.to(device)
    discriminator.to("cpu")
    
    # Train the GAN
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader)):
            # Load data and labels onto the device
            text_embeddings = data['text_embedding'].to(device)            
            # Generate fake images using the generator and the text embeddings
            noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to(device)
            fake_images = generator(text_embeddings,noise)
            del noise
            clear_memory()
            fake_images = F.interpolate(fake_images, size=(512, 512), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
            # Train the discriminator
            discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            real_images = data['image'].to("cpu")
            real_labels = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1).to("cpu")
            
            text_embeddings=text_embeddings.to("cpu")
            real_predictions = discriminator(real_images, text_embeddings)
            del real_images
            clear_memory()
            real_predictions=real_predictions.to("cpu")
            real_labels= real_labels.to("cpu")
            real_loss = adversarial_loss(real_predictions, real_labels)
            real_loss=real_loss.to("cpu")
            fake_images=fake_images.to("cpu")
            text_embeddings=text_embeddings.to("cpu")
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images.detach(), text_embeddings)
            fake_predictions=fake_predictions.to("cpu")
            fake_labels = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1).to("cpu")
            fake_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_predictions, fake_labels)
            del fake_labels
            clear_memory()
            fake_loss=fake_loss.to ("cpu")
            discriminator_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
            discriminator_loss=discriminator_loss.to("cpu")
            discriminator_loss.backward()
            discriminator_optimizer.step()

            # Train the generator
            generator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images, text_embeddings)
            del text_embeddings
            del fake_images
            clear_memory()
            fake_predictions=fake_predictions.to(device)
            real_labels=real_labels.to(device)
            generator_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_predictions, real_labels)
            generator_loss=generator_loss.to(device)
            generator_loss.backward()
            generator_optimizer.step()
            del fake_predictions
            del real_labels
            clear_memory()

            # Save generated images and model checkpoints every 500 batches
            if i % 100 == 0:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to(device)
                    text_embeddings = data['text_embedding'].to(device)            
                    fake_images = generator(text_embeddings,noise)
                save_image(fake_images, f"images\generated_images_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.png", normalize=True, nrow=4)
                torch.save(generator.state_dict(), f"models\generator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), f"models\discriminator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                
        # Print loss at the end of each epoch
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}] Discriminator Loss: {discriminator_loss.item()}, Generator Loss: {generator_loss.item()}")
```